# Exibir determinado arraylist, com clique em determinado botão

Tags: java, android, listview

Olá,
Meu xml tem varios botoes como faço para que qaundo eu clicar em um determinado botão carregue um arraylist na listview

exemplo

```
Botão1 clicado -> arraylist<Perguntas> carrega na listview1
Botão2 clicado -> arraylist<Respostas> carrega na listview1
Botão3 clicado -> arraylist<Nulas> carrega na listview1
```

usando sempre a msm listview, atualmente estou fazendo isso com varias activitys criadas uma para cada botão creio que isso não é uma boa pratica.

Answer (score 0):

Basta mudar o Adapter da sua ListView. Por exemplo:

```
botao1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
             mudaLista(listaDePerguntas);

    });
botao2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
             mudaLista(listaDeRespostas);

    });
```

Agora na sua Activity, crie o metodo que muda a lista

```
private void mudaLista(List<Texto> lista){
    listView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<Texto>(this,  R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item, lista));
}
```

É importante lembrar 2 coisas:

1) As classes Perguntas, Respostas e Nulas tem que ser filhas da classe Texto. Se, no seu codigo, elas ja tiverem pai, use-o no lugar de Texto.

2)A sua ListView tem que ser um campo da sua classe, ou seja, tem que ser declarada fora dos metodos, e inicializada no onCreate